# Police Have.....vs Police Has

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

The State Police Have Busted the thief or The state police has busted the thief?

According to me,
It is **Have** because police is a group of people. So police is plural noun.

Comment: Note that this may be a US/UK issue.  Whether certain nouns are considered singular or plural can depend on dialect.  (Especially notable with sports teams.)

Comment: @HotLicks Police is a plurale tantum. You can no more make it singular than you can make a mass noun plural. It simply sounds wrong to do so.